# facebook check users permissions from application

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Ive got task to create application which can post data on users friends walls. As far as I know user has to accept permissions that application can post messages on his behalf of his friends walls.

Now I would like to make it like:

If user chooses friend to post message on his wall I would like to check whether receiver has got my app installed. If yes then message is post on his wall. If not invitation is sent.

Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

See the `installed` property of the `user` graph object.

Comment: but it throws an error if user hasnt authorized the app yet :(

Comment: Correct, your user has to authenticate your app to for your app to see if their friend is also authorized.  You wanted to know if the friend had auth'd it correct?

Comment: yes I want to know if my friend has authenticated this app. Is it possible without him to authenticate it first ?

Comment: My user has authenticated this app, now I would like to know if my friends has authorized it

Comment: Query the Graph API's `User` object for each friend, and look at the `installed` parameter.